# Code outputs random symbols, i'm unsure what is wrong

Tags: c++, string, loops

I've made a program that shortens full names to initials, and removes any spaces between what has been entered. It did work before but now it prints the initials but also random symbols? I can't really figure out why it's doing it. I'm new to programming also.

This is my code:

```
 // This code removes the spaces from the inputted name 

char *removeSpaces(char *str) 
{ 
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    while (str[i]) 
    { 
        if (str[i] != ' ') 
           str[j++] = str[i]; 
        i++; 
    } 
    str[j] = '\0'; 
    return str; 
} 

// This code takes the users name, and shortens (sh) it

int main(void) {

    char str[100],sh[20];
    int j=0;

    cout<<"Enter Full Name :";
    cin.getline(str,30);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
      {
       if(i==0){
         sh[j]=str[i];
         sh[++j]=' ';
        }

       else if(str[i]==' '){
         sh[++j]=str[i+1];
         sh[++j]=' ';
        }
       }

// This then takes the remove spaces code, and prints the initials with a new line

    cout << removeSpaces(sh) <<endl;
    cout << "\n" <<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

[Picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uer0B.png)

Comment: "It did work before but " What did you change? When was that?

Comment: I don't think I changed anything, i literally saved it and left. But I must have accidently changed something? It was a few days ago I last touched it

Comment: Your code looks okay. The only thing that is bothering me is if you send something like `"some text"` to `str`, you'd be invoking undefined behavior because string literals are constant in C++.

Comment: Can you please post the whole program instead of posting only one function.

Comment: Please make a [mre], including input. Make this function process a hard-coded array  or also provide the input.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  We have no idea when, where, or how that function is invoked, what the data sent to it looks like, etc.  I could easily crash your program if given `int main() { removeSpaces(nullptr); }`

Comment: @LaurenMorgan Some IDEs will show you when changes take place. Not a perfect solution, but could at least give you a hint of what line changed.

Comment: I've edited it so it includes my whole program now

Comment: What is the reason for the `for` loop in `main`?  Isn't `removeSpaces` supposed to do all of that work?  Also, having `strlen` as part of the `for` condition is a very bad way of either introducing off-by-one errors, or horribly inefficient processing due to calling `strlen` on each iteration.  Imagine if the string had 1000 characters.  But why are you not using `std::string` and its functions, since you are writing C++?

Comment: `i<strlen(str)` could overrun `sh` if you're not careful.

Comment: Suddenly no longer working could be a sign of undefined behavior, such as when you neglect to null-terminate a string...

Comment: I'm extremely new to programming. So I know that some of it is written terribly, i apologise. I will try and amend it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The loop in `main` removes all but the first character and those that immediately follow a space, thus: "abc def ghi" becomes "a d g"

Comment: This is just one of the reasons you should be using std::string. You will be just as confused when you are trying to compare two c-strings with == . It will work for std::string but it will work in wondrous ways for  c-strings.

Comment: @LaurenMorgan [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01642df0f6cba244)

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica -- Yes, but you would think that a routine called `removeSpaces` should be doing that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing adding string terminator character ('\0') to string sh. Below is the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *removeSpaces(char *str) 
{ 
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    while (str[i]) 
    { 
        if (str[i] != ' ') 
           str[j++] = str[i]; 
        i++; 
    } 
    str[j] = '\0'; 
    return str; 
} 

// This code takes the users name, and shortens (sh) it

int main(void) {

    char str[100],sh[100];
    int j=0;

    cout<<"Enter Full Name :";
    cin.getline(str,30);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
      {
       if(i==0){
         sh[j]=str[i];
         sh[++j]=' ';
        }

       else if(str[i]==' '){
         sh[++j]=str[i+1];
         sh[++j]=' ';
        }
       }

       sh[j+1] = '\0';

// This then takes the remove spaces code, and prints the initials with a new line

    cout << removeSpaces(sh) <<endl;
    cout << "\n" <<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Enter Full Name :ra me ge
rmg

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out a line (I guess) after the `for` loop in your `main` function, which means your string is potentially not null-terminated.

Using the same (correct) logic you have in your `removeSpaces` function, just add this line **immediately after** the `for` loop in `main`:

```c
sh[++j] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't terminate `sh` with `\0` after you're done, yet `removeSpaces()` expects a null character at the end of the string. Because of this, `removeSpaces()` could go past your intended boundary.

Just add this line after your `for` in `main()`:

```
sh[++j] = '\0\;
```

---

**Word of warning:** You should always make sure that `j` is < 20 (the size of `sh`) before you set it. Otherwise, you could go past the boundary of `sh`. That could also become a source of problems.